# How to upload Image files to an existing database?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I am developing a news website and it's database has 4 columns called id, title, post and views.And I want to have an image for my every article how can I edit my database for this?

And can I upload photos from form just like uploading another info.I mean will I use `INSERT INTO`.I hope I could explain.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The best method would be to store the file name in the database and save the actual file in your filesystem. You can then reference the file name in the database and find it in your filesystem and retrieve it. It is possible to save images to a database, but really not recommended. To do that you would use the MySQL `blob` type. See this page for more information: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html

Comment: it's a bit of a huge thing here, why not answer this question first: do you only need to store the images paths in the database after uploading the files, or do you want to encode the image itself to store them direct in the base?

Comment: I didn't understand I guess.Do you recommend me to use my hosting, database or something else??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have can insert the images into the database just like other information. For that purpose, you have to use blob data type for database attribute. After that, your image will be saved into the database.
If you need to update your existing table then you have to alter your database table. For this purpose, you can query like given below.

```
alter table table_name add `image` mediumblob NOT NULL
```

Please go through this link, you will find it quite helpful.
http://www.anyexample.com/programming/php/php_mysql_example__image_gallery_(blob_storage).xml

Comment: can you explain how to do that on an existing database

Comment: @BurakDemirelli i have updated my answer. Please check it and let me is it working for you ?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a new column called **image**. There are several ways to do this.

To upload a picture you should add enctype= multipart/form-data to the form. Then you can use $_FILES to handle the file uploads. And yes, you can use the same way as $_POST for the $_POST values but for the image you need to use $_FILES.

A really really really easy solution:

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image">
```

And don't forget the submit of course. But make sure you put a type="file" in this form.

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['image'])) {
    $file_name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $file_tmp = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, "images/" . $file_name);
}
```

You can use the same code as you did but you only need to add the file upload handling.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can store images into your database in `blob` format:

```
INSERT INTO news(id,image) VALUES(1,LOAD_FILE('path/to/image'));
```

Or you can store unique value into `news` table, `image_name` column. This value coresponds with real image name, for example `123456.jpg`. Then you can load image in your application based on previously store `image_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Using datatype `VARCHAR` with size `250` in `database`

```
<form action="php.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image">
    <input type="submit" name="sub_pic">
</form>
```

**php.php**

```
if (isset($_POST['sub_pic'])) {

$image_dir = './image/'; //directory you want your image to be saved
$imagename = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$imagetempname = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$imagetype = $_FILES['image']['type'];
$imagesize = $_FILES['image']['size'];

$imagepath = $image_dir . $imagename; //store image path for access

$imageresult = move_uploaded_file($imagetempname, $imagepath); //combine also for access

//if it fails tell the user something
if (!$imageresult)
{
    echo "<script>alert('Error uploading banner!!..Please try again')</script>";
    exit();
}
if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $imagename = addslashes($imagename);
    $imagepath = addslashes($imagepath);
}

//query to insert into database
$query = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO table (image) VALUES ('$imagepath')");


}
```